# Which pair of add / addi instructions implements f = b + c + 9?

Tags: assembly, mips

> For the following C statement `f = b+ c+9`, which is the corresponding
> MIPS assembly code? Assume that the variables a, b and f are given and
> could be considered 32-bit integers as declared in a C program. Use a
> minimal number of MIPS assembly instructions (no subtraction
> instruction) .
>
> - A. `add f, a, b`; `addi f, f,-9`
> - B. `add f, b, c`; `addi f,f,9`
> - C. `addi f, a, b`; `addi f,f,-9`
> - D. `addi F, b, c`; `addi, f, f,9`

I'm looking for the correct answer. I tried to figure it out but I can't. I think the answer is B.

Comment: Since you're not sure, have you tried testing it for some sample input in a MIPS simulator like MARS?  It seems extremely easy to rule out the wrong answers here, e.g. two of the wrong answers read `a` which isn't part of the formula.  Although it is strange that the C statement reads `b` and `c`, but the problem text doesn't tell you that `c` is in a register like `a`, `b`, and `f` are.  Also as @PaulHankin points out, options C. and D. use `addi` (immediate) with register sources.  `clang -target mips` rejects that, as does MARS.

Comment: https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_Languages/Introduction_To_MIPS_Assembly_Language_Programming_(Kann)/03%3A_MIPS_Arithmetic_and_Logical_Operators/3.02%3A_Addition_in_MIPS_Assembly — two are trivially wrong because of -9, two because of c, one because of F, two because of addi without an immediate.. only one can even possibly be remotely correct (and it is, assuming the three letters represent registers).

Comment: Can you explain why you think any of the others could be correct?  Is it `addi` vs. `add` that you aren't sure about?